# having trouble getting base::by() in R to work

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the base::by() function to work in R.
it's very similar to the base::tapply() function.  For some reason,
the following code is not working correctly.

I've tried this:

```
by(data = mtcars[,c("mpg","hp")],
   INDICES = list(mtcars$vs,
                  mtcars$am), 
   FUN = mean)
```

but I get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

mtcars$mpg and mtcars$hp are numeric, so not sure why the mean() can't accept them as arguments.  Anyone know why this may be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @duckmayr the `FUN`ction gets a dataframe and not individual columns. Alternatively, you can use `colMeans` function which works on dataframes.

```
by(data = mtcars[,c("mpg","hp")],
   INDICES = list(mtcars$vs,mtcars$am), 
   FUN = colMeans)


#: 0
#: 0
#    mpg      hp 
# 15.050 194.167 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#: 1
#: 0
#     mpg       hp 
# 20.7429 102.1429 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#: 0
#: 1
#    mpg      hp 
# 19.750 180.833 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#: 1
#: 1
#    mpg      hp 
#28.3714 80.5714
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `mean()` is getting a `data.frame` of the observations of `mtcars[ , c("mpg", "hp")]` that match each of the four conditions. In other words, `by()` doesn't `apply` the function `FUN` across the columns of the subsetted dataframe, it uses the function *directly* on the subsetted dataframe.

Try something like this:

```
by(data = mtcars[ , c("mpg", "hp")],
   INDICES = mtcars[ , c("vs", "am")],
   FUN = function(x) sapply(x, mean))

vs: 0
am: 0
     mpg       hp 
 15.0500 194.1667 
------------------------------------------ 
vs: 1
am: 0
      mpg        hp 
 20.74286 102.14286 
------------------------------------------ 
vs: 0
am: 1
     mpg       hp 
 19.7500 180.8333 
------------------------------------------ 
vs: 1
am: 1
     mpg       hp 
28.37143 80.57143
```